# draw latitudes and longitudes on a map with a Winkel projection

Tags: grids, map

How to overlay representations of longitudes and latitudes on this map[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winkel_tripel_projection.  You will also need the size of the image (without extra white space).